# Detect overflow when using -webkit-line-clamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to check that there is an overflow when using `-webkit-line-clamp`, so that a "see more" button can be shown if there is an overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare scrollHeight and clientHeight properties of element:

```
function hasOwerflow(element) {
    return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
}
```

Comment: When using -webkit-line-clamp I'm getting that scrollHeight is the same es clientHeight.